# Reset ScrollView to the top after render (react-navigation v4)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, scrollview

How can I reset the ScrollView to the top of it each time I navigate to the screen where said ScrollView is located? (I'm using `react-navigation` v4).

I've seen a post where the solution implies the use of:

`import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";`

and then use a hook:

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused();
useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
        scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo(0, 0, true);
    }
}, [isFocused]);
```

However, since I'm using v4, that option is not available for my project. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `react-navigation v4` an, here is how you can scroll the `ScrollView` to the top on screen focus:

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Button, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

export default function Screen1({navigation}) {
  const scrollViewRef = React.createRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      scrollViewRef?.current?.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});
    });

    return () => focusListener.remove();
  }, [navigation, scrollViewRef]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title={'Go to screen 2'}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('screen2')}
      />
      <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 300,
            borderWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 15,
            marginTop: 10,
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            height: 600,
            borderWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 15,
            marginTop: 10,
          }}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            height: 200,
            borderWidth: 1,
            marginHorizontal: 15,
            marginTop: 10,
          }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The basic idea is:

- Create a `ref` and assign it to the `ScrollView`
- Add `didFocus` listener provided by the `react-navigation`
- Use `scrollViewRef?.current?.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: true});` to scroll the `ScrollView` to the top

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to your problem is to use React Ref hook, just pass the ref of your scrollable component to their useScrollToTop hook.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native"



function demo() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null)

  useIsFocused(ref)

  return <ScrollView ref={ref}>{/* content */}</ScrollView>
}
```

References:

[Snack.expo.io Example](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=useScrollToTop%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.4.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.7.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.4.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.3.7%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E3.10.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E0.7.3%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.4.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.14.0&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fuse-scroll-to-top.js)

[React Navigation Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-scroll-to-top/)